# Is it possible to buy a used Samsung phone with fake/hacked Android ROM that looks like the official one and may spy on you?

Tags: security, rom, operating-system

I have a used Samsung phone. I wonder if it is possible to have a malicious ROM uploaded that looks like the official one that may allow the hacker to spy on the user. Can I make sure that I have the official ROM? The system updates are downloaded and seems legit. Also I checked *Settings* -> *Device Status* that states "official". Is it enough or these information can be forged?

Comment: Everything Android OS displays to you may be forged. Therefore you have to go down to those components you can not simply replace or modify. One such component is the bootloader, check what it displays regarding e.g. the state of the bootloader lock.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I rebooted the device to Recovery Menu (volume up + power), then Reboot to Bootloader. After the restart the bottom line shows: DEVICE STATE: locked. As I also investigated, if the device is in the locked state, the installed os is verified, so if something were changed the system wouldn't start. More information is here: https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/device-state.

Comment: As I wrote the locked state is only one of the values displayed by bootloader. I would recommend to check them all, especially the knox fuse/flag.